# how do I show a regular language is equal to another?

Tags: regular-language

So this is related to regular languages,their quotient, and closure properties.  I am suppose first answer if the question is true or false and then explain why.  I dont know how to answer the following question.

1.)
Which of the following identities are true?
(L/a)a = L (the left side represents the concatenation of the languages L/a and {a}).

Answer (score 0):

If they are not equal, this is most easily shown by a counterexample. Equality is usually shown by proving the inclusion in both directions.

Here, take for example `L = {b}`. Then `L/a = L` and thus `(L/a)a = {ba}`, which is not equal to L.